# Is there a way to access open finder windows with Quicksilver?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, finder, path, quicksilver

If I have two finder windows open, and I want to move files from one to the other, without dragging, how should I do this with Quicksilver?

I can select the files in one, and then use the "Get Current Selection" hotkey so that they pop into quicksilver, and I can select the "Move To" action, but what is the best way to get them to the other folder?

I often run into this with Quicksilver: I wish I could list which finder windows are open and then do things with their paths. Anyone know if that is possible? If not, how do we recommend it to some QS developers?

Comment: The developers have ceased development of Quicksilver as far as I know.

Comment: QS does not index current opening Finder folders.
QS is still under active development. See http://qsapp.com and http://groups.google.com/group/blacktree-quicksilver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QS has the User Interface plugin that gives access to windows (and a bunch of other things, like menu items). Sadly, there's no way to get back to a window's path (since this is Finder-specific, not all windows "represent" something on-disk), so that's a no — for the time being, but feel free to open an issue on [QS issue tracker](https://github.com/quicksilver/quicksilver/issues)

Comment: thank you! (to the creator of quicksilver, no less! :)

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks ;-). I'm not the creator, alcor is. I'm just the one that has been (mostly) maintaining it throughout the Dark Ages, and still am.